# How to Get values for DB configuration from some database Tables in CakePHP ?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am making an application that will be installed at multiple clients , and DB configuration for every client will be different , as i will be using multiple different databases LIKE Oracle and MySql. 
One database will be common in all , i have made a table in same where i will save the db config details , now how to pick that data from the table at database.php .

Can't find anything bit confused .`class DATABASE_CONFIG {

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'hrportal_imp',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
); 
//want to fetch data from x table from Default datasource.
public $ora = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Oracle',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => '<IP i get from above db>',
            'port' => '1521',
            'login' => '<Data i get from above db>',
            'password' => '<Data i get from above db>',
    'database' => '<IP i get from above db>:1521/orcl',
            'prefix' => '',
    'sid' => 'orcl'

);
```

}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it by Placing the same in Beforefilter of AppController .

```
App::import('Model', 'ConnectionManager');
        ConnectionManager::create('ora',
        $config = array('datasource' => 'Database/Oracle',
                        'persistent' => false,
                        'host' => 'dynamic Host',
                        'port' => '1521',
                        'login' => 'HCM',
                        'password' => 'hdhd',
                        'database' => 'dynamic host:1521/dhdh',
                        'prefix' => '',
                        'sid' => 'orcl')
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

by default, cakephp will use "default" configurations that you can write within your $default variable. you can also change your database connection as per requirements too. you can check your current selected database on your controller too.

```
App::import('Model', 'ConnectionManager');
$ds = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
echo $ds->config['database'];
```

Comment: This is just to view the database name ,

Comment: yes. i just gave you an example. you can change ur current database by this way conditionaly whenever you need to select an another database.                                                                                             $ds = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('ora');
echo $ds->config['database']; thanks